# AHK (AutoHotKey) Concatenate strings and variable

Tags: autohotkey, autocad

I have this code for sending command to Autocad. It works OK.

```
{
GetAcad() ;Creates global variable ACAD where Application Object is stored
CADdoc:= ACAD.activedocument
Layer:= "0"
CADdoc.SendCommand("_-LAYER _SET " %Layer% " `n`n") ;;Uses COM 
CADdoc.SendCommand("_CHPROP _LA " %Layer% " `n`n")  ;;Uses COM
sleep, 50
send, {Escape}
sleep, 50
send, {Escape}
return
}
```

Tried to create function with Layer parameter

```
ACADChangeLayer("Layer_Name") ;This is how is the function called

ACADChangeLayer(Layer)
{
  GetAcad()
  global ACAD   ;because I global variable has given value outside this function
  ACAD.activedocument.SendCommand("_-LAYER _SET " %Layer% " `n`n")
  ACAD.activedocument.SendCommand("_CHPROP _LA " %Layer% " `n`n")
  sleep, 50
  send, {Escape}
  sleep, 50
  send, {Escape}
}
```

Doesn't work as expected, tried figure out why...

```
ACADChangeLayer(Layer)
  {
    GetAcad()
    global ACAD
    msgbox, % acad.activedocument.name
    msgbox, %Layer%
    CommandSetActiveLayer:= ("_-LAYER _SET " %Layer% " `n`n")
    msgbox, %CommandSetActiveLayer%
    ...
  }
```

1. First MsgBox shows proper DocumentName (`drawing1.dwg`)
2. Second MsgBoxu shows Proper LayerName (`Layer_Name` - see second code block above)
3. Third MsgBox shows only part before variable (`"_-LAYER _SET "`) **Why?**

Thank you for advice.

[image]

Comment: Works fine here. What do you mean by "part before variable"? Could you show us the screenshot?

Comment: Yes, of course: [Screenshot](https://ctrlv.cz/Qh9p)

Comment: Text in MsgBox has to be `_-LAYER _SET Layer_Name ` (with two newlines at the end)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the assignment line that should be written as one of the following:

```
CommandSetActiveLayer := "_-LAYER _SET " . Layer . "`n`n"
CommandSetActiveLayer := ("_-LAYER _SET " . Layer . "`n`n")

CommandSetActiveLayer = "_-LAYER _SET " %Layer% `n`n
```

The first two lines use the newer expression method with the concatenate operator
(dot `.`), while the second line uses the traditional method.

Reference : [Variables and Expressions](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm).

Comment: Thanks for answer. This is exactly what I was looking for and didn't see it when I had it in front of my eyes (facepalm). Do you have an idea why `.SendCommand("_-LAYER _SET " %Layer% " `n`n")` works outside function?

Comment: By default expressions passed as function parameters are evaluated in the legacy/traditional method, so this works. By using the newer `:=` operator, you forced evaluation in the new non-traditional method, which caused the problem.

Comment: Interesting, I was confused, because `.SendCommand` worked as expected outside the function, but not inside (with same notation - with `%var%`). Thank you again, I appreciate your effort!